# Можно ли сказать "Девушка НЕЖНО ступала"?

Tags: безграмотность

"Легко ступать" - устойчивое словосочетание. Можно ли сказать "она нежно ступала"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле, слово "нежно" относится к воздействию на другой объект. Можно нежно посмотреть на кого-то, нежно его коснуться. То есть, скажем так, "нежно" - это и ощущение того, на кого оказано воздействие, и чувства, которые вложил в действие человек.
То есть, конечно, хотелось бы видеть контекст, но, думаю, если речь идет просто о походке, то лучше придумать другое прилагательное. Например, "мягко ступала".

Comment: Речь идёт о походке. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Если по спине любимого, то да.

Comment: Только если она "строинькая и лёхонькая".)